# Forward Declaration in a nested namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm having a problem with forward declarations in a nested namespace. I put a forward declaration for a class or struct in a nested namespace and when I try to use it in the parent of that namespace I get an error. I don't know what to do.

This is what the code looks like:

```
#include "Data\Types.hpp"

namespace GameEngine
{
    class Console
    {
    public:
        class Renderer : public RenderComponent2D
        {
        public:
            Renderer(Console*, const GameEngine::DataProcessing::FontData*);
//...
```

and in Data\Types.hpp:

```
namespace GameEngine
{
    namespace DataProcessing
    {
        struct FontData;
//...
```

and the error MinGW gives me is :

```
'FontData' in namespace 'GameEngine::DataProcessing' does not name a type
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions with this problem.

Comment: Try just `const DataProcessing::FontData *`.

Comment: Post a small program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/CoOw1).

Comment: @Rob thanks for trying the code, I still don't know what the issue is. It might be some recursive include somewhere, I've gotten that a few times on large projects.

Comment: A small note: You should use the forward slash in the `#include`, even under Windows. As is, you produce undefined behaviour, and there *might* some (current or future) compiler which doesn't like it (because it doesn't special-case string constants in `#include` directives and thus interprets `\T` as escape sequence). Not to mention that one day you might want to port your program to a different system which doesn't use backslashes as directory separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be problem in declaration of method. You are already inside GameEngine namespace:

```
namespace GameEngine
{
    class Console
```

But in declaration you use this namespace too :

```
 Renderer(Console*, const GameEngine::DataProcessing::FontData*);
```

Try it without GameEngine :

```
 Renderer(Console*, const DataProcessing::FontData*);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently that turned out to be an unclosed namespace, e.g.

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        class C {};
// failed to close both namespaces properly here
```

What threw me off the trail a bit is that the unclosed namespace was actually in a secondary file being included in my cpp file.  Try poking around in your headers to see if any of them have unclosed namespaces.