# Can I avoid nested namespaces in forward declaration?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

As of January 2018, what is the most modern style for forward declarations? We use something like below, but is there a more compact version?

Could I write something like `class Foo::Bar` (does not work for me, but maybe I miss a newer C++ standard)? Or any more compact version?

Current style:

```
namespace Foo
{
    class SimpleCommandParser;

    namespace Bar
    {
        class Parts;
        class Situation;
        class Callsign;
    }
    namespace Yep
    {
        class AircraftSnapshot;
        class Aircraft;
    }
}
```

There are some questions about similar topics like [Forward Declaration in a nested namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9244834/356726) , but they are quite old.

Comment: Which C++ standard can your compiler/compilers deal with?

Comment: I like to keep that open. Is there a way in any modern C++ standard as of today? If so, I might change my compiler, or keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of January 2018, forward declaration of a name into a namespace is still the same as it was since first version of the standard i.e. the declaration must be within that namespace.

> Could I write something like `class Foo::Bar`

Not in a current (C++17) standard.

There has been a proposal [P0289R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf) to add just such feature, but it hasn't been followed through and such change hasn't been introduced to the standard as of C++17.